# google blogspot using editor name

Tags: text, text-editor

In Google BlogSpot, what type of editor they are using for type the message/comment/post,

please find attachment,

[BlogSpot Screenshot http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/2656/blogspoteditorname.jpg](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/2656/blogspoteditorname.jpg)

Comment: You should accept more answers to your older questions.

Comment: +1 for hand-drawn arrow!