# Where can I get Google Blogger's WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: wysiwyg, blogger

I am working on a Windows 8 blogger app and I searched for different WYSIWYG editors but none was as good and clean as the blogger post editor and to complete this project I need blogger post editor source code. Can anyone tell me where to get it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Even closed, I still want you to try **Windows Live Writer**, which I always use.

Comment: relate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127801/google-blogspot-using-editor-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Blogger is open source, you may have to use an alternative.

One good alternative I have used before is CKEditor, failing that there are some mentioned here:

[Alternatives to CKEditor for WSYIWYG text area editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719241/alternatives-to-ckeditor-for-wsyiwyg-text-area-editor)

Comment: Yup, it's not open source and I think I should make my own editor. Anyways, thanks for the suggestion :)